# Video playlist images strech the outher div and video player

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, preact

Hi I trying to make video player with playlist but my problem is that whenever i load thumbnails for video it strech video to its height.In this example its keeps with but its looks ugly and on mobile its just horrible, is it easier solution to my problem.For video I use plugin for tailiwnd

> @tailwindcss/aspect-ratio

```
import { useState } from "preact/hooks"


const videoList = [
    {
        title: "video 1",
        videoId: "r9jwGansp1E"
    },
    {
        title: "video 2",
        videoId: "ma4eB_rgGuA"
    },
    {
        title: "video 3",
        videoId: "hSva6NSW1Xc"
    },
    {
        title: "video 4",
        videoId: "CLeZyIID9Bo"
    },
    {
        title: "video 5",
        videoId: "cInjxeFTKwk"
    },
    {
        title: "video 6",
        videoId: "aMldpZF6GBU"
    },
]



export const VideosMainPage = () => {
    const [videoSelected, setVideoSelected] = useState<number>(0)

    return (
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-4 ">
            <div class="aspect-w-16 aspect-h-9 md:col-span-3">
                {
                    videoList.map(({ title, videoId }, index) => {
                        if (videoSelected === index) {
                            return (
                                <iframe src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`} frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen loading="lazy"
                                    alt={title}
                                ></iframe>
                            )
                        }
                    })
                }

            </div>
            <div class="rounded-md bg-slate-800  md:col-span-1 ">
                <p class="text-center text-white mt-2 font-bold text-lg  mb-2">Wybierz Video</p>
                <hr class="bg-blue-500 h-1 mb-2" />
                <div class="w-full h-full max-h-96  overflow-y-auto">
                    <div class="flex flex-col pt-2 w-full justify-center mb-1">
                        {videoList.map(({ title, videoId }, index) => (
                            <img src={`http://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/0.jpg`} alt={title} class="w-1/2 object-cover object-center mx-auto  max-h-24 pb-4 last:pb-0 cursor-pointer" key={title} onClick={() => setVideoSelected(index)} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Edit: Images to show a problem

1st image is how it looks now it keep it in normal video playe hight by using max-height property

[image]

and 2nd image whene i remove

> max-h-96
> witch i add to staticly keep video player hight even whener scroll-y is on it stretch the window idk why

[image]

Comment: Hi IvonaK, Thanks for providing the code. Can you also provide two images, one of the broken behavior and one of the desired behavior (this one can be a sketch)?

Comment: Hi images are comming from youtube api `http://img.youtube.com/vi/[youtube video id]/0.jpg`

Comment: By Images, I mean screenshots of what the website looks like. I need a visual to understand what is wrong with the styling.

Comment: @PhilipClark i added examples , 1st with styles in exmaple in this question 2nd without max hight

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set a fixed height on the **scroll area** or add a fixed-height container wrapping the video player and scroll area. The video seems to be in a flex container with the scroll area. Thus when there are more videos or they are taller, the scroll area scales up, which in turn scales the height of the video.